# Overriding CSS Selectors for only certain elements - Sencha

Tags: css, extjs, css-selectors, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This is a dumb question - but I've been stuck on it for awhile and cannot find an answer.

I'm trying to override the color of an Ext.js checkbox for only certain elements.

CSS:

.x-field-checkbox .x-field-mask::after, .x-field-radio .x-field-mask::after **.emptyCell**{
    color: white;
}

Notice the class there - .emptyCell

Now the Sencha code:

```
    if(noCheckBox) {
        var checkbox = 
            {    
                    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                    cls: 'opBuyoffCheckBoxCell emptyColumn',
                    readOnly: true
            };
        return checkbox;
    } else {
        var checkbox = 
            {    
                    xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                    cls: 'opBuyoffCheckBoxCell',
                    listeners: {
                          change: function (checkbox) {
                             //Todo put in logic on checkbox change 
                          }
                   }
            };
        return checkbox;
    }
},
```

What is the problem here? I have three checkboxes.  Two of them should render white and the other one should be normal based on my CSS and logic.  I've debugged and it is going into the right code.  But when I launch my application it is always using the emptyColumn css class.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What code you have written for defined cls? Can you post that one?

Comment: You say **emptyCell**, but the code contains **emptyColumn**. Is it just a typo?

Comment: just add a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) to see your code clearly

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css:

```
.emptyColumn .x-input-el:checked+.x-field-mask::after {
    color: #fff;
}
```

One thing to notice, write same cls in CSS and HTML.